# A Cauchy problem : How can I find the following solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose that we have the following time-dependent partial differential equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial V(t, x)}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 x\frac{\partial^2 V(t, x)}{\partial x^2}+ \theta(m-x)\frac{\partial V(t,x)}{\partial x} - wxV(t, x), \quad t> 0, x\in \mathbb{R} \\
V(0, x ) = f(x) = e^{-ux}, \quad x\in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

where $\theta > 0$, $m>0$, $\sigma >0$, $u\in \mathbb{R}$, and $w\in \mathbb{R}$ are constants.

How can I come up with $\tilde{V}(t, x)$ as an initial solution for the above partial differential equation system? Could you please give me the general instruction on how I should proceed to find such a solution from the above partial differential equation?